# Throttling on specify mime types using Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have a project that I want to throttle the speed on specify mime types, these mime types are as follows:

- application/x-rar-compressed .zip
- application/zip .rar

So my question is straight forward, is it possible to throttle specify mime types in Apache? and if this is the case how do I go about and make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

mod_bw allows limiting speed per Filetype:

```
<Virtualhost *>
BandwidthModule On
ForceBandWidthModule On
LargeFileLimit .avi 1 20000
LargeFileLimit .mpg 1 20000
Servername www.example.com
</Virtualhost>
```

Unfortunately the main site doesnt seem to be maintained anymore, but depending on the distribution you're using it should be trivial to install it.